# Does Cloud Foundy platform supports SIP and RTP?

Tags: sip, cloud-foundry, rtp

There is a conferencing application that I want to build on top of cloud foundry. Does cloud foundry support SIP and RTP protocols?

Answer (score 0):

Inbound Cloud Foundry only supports HTTP and HTTPS through the router component, routing traffic on any other port to an application would not work.